# Java: Generics: Compilation Error When Trying to implment a method defined in an Interface with genrics in the argument

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write an Interface with a setter method that takes in a TreeMap as an argument.

That TreeMap can have objects of classes descended from an AbstractNResource class. The class definition of AbstractNResource is written with generics to let it take in two arguments from two other class hierarchies.

I have had trouble writing a setter method in the Interface that the compiler will accept.

Here is the Interface (with the compile error), I call it IDataLoader:

```
public interface IDataLoader {

        public abstract void setFrameDataMap(    
            // Compile Error: Syntax error on token "extends", , expected
            TreeMap<Long, AbstractNResource<AbstractNRequestableResourceData, INDescriptor>.AbstractFrameData> frameDataMap);
}
```

This is the parent class of the kind of objects that TreeMap can have:

```
public abstract class AbstractNResource<T extends AbstractNRequestableResourceData, D extends INDescriptor>
        extends
        AbstractVizResource<AbstractNRequestableResourceData, IDescriptor>
        implements INResource {

        public abstract class AbstractFrameData {}

        protected TreeMap<Long, AbstractFrameData> frameDataMap;
}
```

Next step down, I have an AbstractDataLoader class that partially implements the Interface IDataLoader:

```
public abstract class AbstractDataLoader<T extends AbstractNatlCntrsRequestableResourceData, D extends INatlCntrsDescriptor>
        implements
        IDataLoader<AbstractNatlCntrsRequestableResourceData, INatlCntrsDescriptor> {}
```

One more step down I have a class WaveSatDataLoader that extends that abstract class.  This is where the compile error is happening:

```
public class WaveSatDataLoader extends
        AbstractDataLoader<WaveSatResourceData, NCMapDescriptor> {

    @Override
    public void setFrameDataMap(TreeMap<Long,AbstractNatlCntrsResource<WaveSatResourceData, NCMapDescriptor>.AbstractFrameData> frameDataMap) {
        System.out.println("To do");
    }

}
```

The compilation error is:

> The method
>   setFrameDataMap(TreeMap.AbstractFrameData>)
>   of type WaveSatDataLoader must override or implement a supertype
>   method

I do not have setFrameDataMap() implmentation in the AbstractDataLoading class, but putting one there hasn't helped.

I am stumped as to why the compiler is complaining.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because you are trying to implement an interface method with a method that has a different signature.

In `IDataLoader`, the second type parameter of the argument to `setFrameDataMap` is

```
AbstractNResource<AbstractNRequestableResourceData, INDescriptor>.AbstractFrameData
```

whereas in `WaveSatDataLoader` it is

```
AbstractNatlCntrsResource<WaveSatResourceData, NCMapDescriptor>.AbstractFrameData
```

I am also confused about whether `IDataLoader` is supposed to be generic or not. You have written

```
implements IDataLoader<AbstractNatlCntrsRequestableResourceData, INatlCntrsDescriptor>
```

yet in the first section of code `IDataLoader` does not have type parameters.

Comment: Hi Paul. In regards to your first comment WaveSatResourceData, & NCMapDescriptor are children of AbstractNRequestableResourceData &  INDescriptor.  I'm under the impression giving the children in place of the parent is kosher in Java.  I am trying to override the interface IDataLoader method to implement it.

Comment: Hi Paul, in regards to your second comment, I put the generics in the definition of IDataLoader so that I could define setFrameData there with the 'T' and the 'D' as a means getting IDataLoader to compile, and ultimately to get overriden (for implementation ) forms of setFrameDataMap to accept WaveSatResourceData, & NCMapDescriptor, as well as other children of AbstractNRequestableResourceData & INDescriptor

Comment: Giving child in place of parent is OK as a return type, but not as a method argument.